# Infinite scroll with CustomScrollView Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to know how can I implement an infinite scroll with CustomScrollView in Flutter.

On init, I have the call to load the items, it works. But, I would like to launch again the call on provider to re-load again, but I can re-launch because I don't have a context to call the provider in the onScroll function.

Currently, I have this :

```
class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
final _scrollController = ScrollController();
double _prevScrollPos = 0.0;

_onScroll() {
    double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    double currentScrollPos = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    double delta = 200.0;

    if (maxScroll - currentScrollPos <= delta && _prevScrollPos - currentScrollPos < 0) {
        print('load... I would like to call my provider to load the others posts with addPost()');
        //Provider.of<GlobalFeeds>(context, listen: false).addPost();

        // to fix the unlimited call on onScroll function
        _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.pixels);
    }

    _prevScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
}

_addPost(context) {
    Provider.of<GlobalFeeds>(context, listen: false).addPost();
}

@override
void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);

    Timer.run(() {
        _addPost(context);
    });

    super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final globalFeeds = Provider.of<GlobalFeeds>(context);
    final posts = globalFeeds.posts;

    return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
            ...
        ),
        SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            final Post post = posts[index];

            return PostContainer(post: post);
            },
            childCount: posts.length,
            ),
        ),
        ],
    )
    );
}
}
```

To init my list, I call in initState() :

```
Timer.run(() {
    _addPost(context);
});
```

I don't know if it's a good practice. Do you have an idea how can I implement this functionality, to have a context in onScroll function or to have a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```dart
  itemBuilder: (index, context) {
    if(items.length < index) {
      return items[index-1];
    }
    else {
      return FutureBuilder(/*...*/); // your loading widget which
    }                          // becomes the new item once loaded
  }
```

also get rid of the `childCount`.

Answer (score 0):

I did just that in my [example project](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/infinite-scrolling-sliverlist-in-flutter-2236aa050a6c) with `CustomScrollView`, `SliverAppBar` and `SliverList.separated()`. I wrapped them with `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` like below and calling `onScrollListener()` to load next page:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
    onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
      if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
        onScrollListener();
      }

      return true;
    },
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: const Text('Infinite scrolling SliverList'),
        ),
        SliverList.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            // Show progress indicator on the bottom
            if (allFlowers.value.length == index) {
              return const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              );
            }

            final flowerName = allFlowers.value[index];

            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 16),
              child: Text(
                flowerName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: isPageLoading.value ? allFlowers.value.length + 1 : allFlowers.value.length,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
void onScrollListener() {
  if (reachedEnd.value) {
    return;
  }

  if (!isPageLoading.value) {
    isPageLoading.value = true;
    Future.microtask(() async {
      final newFlowers = await getFlowersUseCase.getFlowers(page: nextPage.value);
      if (newFlowers.length < pageSize) {
        reachedEnd.value = true;
      } else {
        nextPage.value++;
      }

      allFlowers.value.addAll(newFlowers);
      isPageLoading.value = false;
    });
  }
}
```